# Keyboard shortcuts not working anymore in xfce

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

Although everything was working perfectly well, keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, etc. have suddenly stopped working in my Xubuntu 14/Xfce4 installation.

Nothing happens if I hit them, and oddly, if I try to close a terminal by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, the letters `;3S` get written in the console.

Of course, the shortcuts in "Settings>Window Manager>Keyboard" are all correctly configured, and I have checked in `xev` that the keys are still mapped correctly.

- Output of `ps -ef | grep xfce`: http://pastebin.com/R44JZBP5
- Output of `cat ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`http://pastebin.com/GY7NzxCV

Where could this come from ?

**EDIT: I localized the problem: it comes from xmodmap:**

I have a `.Xmodmap` file in my home folder, containing only

```
keycode  21 = asciicircum dead_grave dead_circumflex dead_grave dead_tilde dead_ogonek dead_tilde
keycode  77 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
```

(so nothing related to `Alt`). If I remove it, shortcuts work again. Why ? How could I have both working at the same time ?

Comment: What happens if you rebind it under `xfce4-keyboard-settings` or test another combination for `Alt+F4` ?

Comment: Did you have activated some special keys like [Fn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) ?

Comment: Completely resetting xfce by deleting ~/.conf/xfce4 did not help either.

Comment: Is your alt key working?

Comment: I have the same problem which started recently on Ubuntu 14.04. Some keys work (Alt-F4) but not all (Alt-F2), and I think none of the keys I set in the XFCE keyboard shortcuts work

Comment: Just happened to me, Ubuntu 14.04. I rebooted after accepting some updates, so I don't know if the reboot or the updates caused it. Very frustrating. It's things like this that prevent Linux from ever reaching the mainstream.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it could be [bug #1292290 - 
Window manager keybindings don't work after reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1292290). A workaround is mentioned there:

> I found a workaround: clear before reassign!
>
> To make a shortcut to work ok, select an action you want to reassign
>   and click 'Clear' button until it will really empty. Sometime if there
>   is some (hidden?) duplicates, you will still see some shortcut (the same
>   or different), even you clicked 'Clear' button. In this case just
>   click the button again. Since the action shortcut is really empty,
>   just assign your custom one as usual, and it will work ok :)

and

> Someone on #xubuntu or #ubuntustudio (can't remember) mentioned a
>   workaround for this:
>
> You simply have to delete the current key mapping twice before setting
>   a new one. Then the new mapping will be stored in the config.

Comment: Probably not, since it is affected by xmodmap (see my edit).

Comment: Clear before reassign new keybinding do the job (for 14.04)

Answer (score 2):

After suffering from the same problem for months (yes, `xmodmap` is to blame), I have finally found a workaround:

`setxkbmap -option` will reset the state of the Alt key.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to still be an active issue. I found a solution for Studio Ubuntu 14.04 that should work for other xubuntus:

1. Set your file manager to "show hidden files"
2. Navigate to `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/`
3. Open `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` in a text editor

Look for two lines:

- `<property name="<Alt>Tab" type="empty">` should be first
- `<property name="<Alt>Tab" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>` has to come after that

You could search on "Tab" to locate these more quickly. If either of these are missing or they are out of order or the wrong value is assigned, then the Alt-Tab function will not work. Fixing a missing value assignment got my computer working right again. (I had disabled Alt-Tab while working with Inkscape and could not get it back again until I did this).

Be careful in there! You might want to make a backup before fooling around in this file

Answer (score 0):

In Xfce4 (v4.14.1) keyboard shortcut window has a bug. It doesn't close after set the shortcut. For this you must edit the shortcut yourself. Your file is that: **~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml**

After editing this file you must restart your computer.

```
<property name="custom" type="empty">
    <property name="&lt;Shift&gt;Print" type="string" value="gnome-screenshot -c -a"/>
......
```