# Xfce4 keybinding and logout randomly not working since Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xfce, logout, shortcut-keys

I upgraded my ubuntu installation from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS a few weeks ago.
Everything works fine except Xfce4.

Since the update, I'm sometimes unable to use my custom keybindings (like alt-F1 in order to open a terminal). It only happens after a reboot, not during a session.

When it happens, I have to force-reboot the whole computer, since I can't logout either. When I try to logout one time, nothing happens. When I try to logout another time, the message `"Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown"` appears.

I think some process is preventing xfce4 from login in/out. However, I tried to disable every autostart process (`~/.config/autostart`) and beside the fact it's faster, it doesn't solve anything.

Do you happen to have any information about that problem?

Thanks !

> Configuration:
>
> - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
> - Xfce4 4.10

Comment: Sounds like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/461203/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-anymore-in-xfce

Comment: Looks similar, however I don't have a `.Xmodmap` file and the default keyboard shortcuts like `Alt+F4` are working fine.

Comment: I'm having exact same issue here. Looks like the whole "Logout" system is bugged in Ubuntu 14.04, as LXDE also randomly fails to logout.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, logout fails and loads of user gui processes still running after each failed logout.

I wouldn't normally use Xfce4, but rdp access is required and unity over rdp is currently broken in 14.04.

Looking forward to either of these issues getting fixed by the point release.  If I can be of any help or provide any more information please let me know.

Comment: Actually this may not be too much of an issue.  This is the 32bit version of 14.04 that was installed on a kvm virtual machine to provide support for legacy 32 bit gui apps that have difficulty running even when ia32-libs is installed.  I don't know if these issues occur on the 64 bit version.  I could therefore just run 12.04.4 32 bit instead as it is good until 2017.  By this time I would hope not to be running any 32 bit gui apps.  However the machine is not heavily used, so I will probably just continue to use Xfce4 and schedule a weekly reboot to clear the unwanted processes.

Comment: The only annoying thing is the UK keyboard mapping not working in Xfce4 on 14.04 32 bit, so need to type from memory of a US keyboard layout.  This is documented as a bug elsewhere.